# Angular: get response from HasChangesGuard in other component

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a `HasChangesGuard` which is injected in the `app.routes.ts` file.
e.g.

```
path: 'SomePath', component: SomeComponent, canDeactivate: [HasChangesGuard], outlet: 'someOutlet' },
```

And suppose I also have a navigation treeview from DevExpress

> HTML

```
<dx-tree-view ... (onItemClick)="onItemClick($event)" ..../>
```

> Typescript

```
public async onItemClick(e: any): Promise<void> {
     ....
     const node: ITreeViewNode = e.itemData;
     this.selectedNode = node; // this setter then adds a css property to the DOM.
}
```

The problem is now, when I am in the treeview and I navigate to `SomeComponent`  and I do some changes without saving them and then click on another item, a dialog pops up because I have declared so in the `HasChangesGuard`, but when clicking cancel. The navigationTreeView has no clue what I pressed and will highlight the clicked node either way.

So how could I pass (or rather await) the result from the `HasChangesGuard` (called by a route change) to the navigation component?